# How to adjust the height of each Accordian Panel

Tags: extjs, layout, height, size, panel

I have the following accordian layout. Each panel takes entire height of the container. Is there any way I could limit the child panels height to be limited to whatever the panel has to display? I tried fill: false and that didn't work.

```
Ext.define('T.view.Test', {
    id: 'Test',
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.Test',
    title: 'PANEL CONTAINER',
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        align: 'stretch',
        pack: 'start',
        fill: false
    },
    height: 300,
    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                flex: 1,
                title: 'panel1',
                html: 'this is first panel'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'panel2',
                flex: 1,
                html: 'this is the next panel'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'panel3',
                flex: 1,
                html: 'this is the 3rd panel'
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.create('T.view.Test', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kavitaC/2c52aby4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill: false` does not work because the panels have `flex: 1`. Just remove `flex` from all panels and that's it!